# How to save opened workbook in the same workbook directory with same file extension but different name using AddIn?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried the following code in *workbookopen* of .xlam file but it saves the **Add-In** and not the *opened running workbook* in the directory.Also the following only works for .xlsm file.
What i really wanted is to save the running instance of excel workbook/s with different file names in current directory with same extension whenever i run the Add-in !

```
 Sub saveas() 
 Dim wbname As String
 Dim pathONLY, filePATH, fileONLY As String
 filePATH = ThisWorkbook.FullName
 fileONLY = ThisWorkbook.Name
 pathONLY = Left(filePATH, Len(filePATH) - Len(fileONLY))
 wbname = "NewFile"
 On Error Resume Next
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=pathONLY & wbname & ".xlsm"
 
 End Sub
```

Comment: What saving the **module** does mean? Do you strangely mean the add-in? This piece of code is designed to create a backup for add-n, when it starts. If you try this code in the add-in `Workbook_Open` event, of course, **the active document is the add-in itself**... Then, what is the use of `On Error Resume Next`? This only not let VBA to raise an error if it is something wrong with the used parameters. It does not help at all, it only may create problems. If you want saving the file with their own extension, do not use ".xlsm", extract the existing extension and use it instead.

Comment: I meant Addin but i mistakely wrote name of that Addin "Module.xlam" . How to save the opened workbook NOT the Addin in this case ?

Comment: Is there only one such a workbook? It should be obvious that you cannot use `ActiveWorkbook` when add-in opens. If you run the code after it has been loaded, it will refer to the real active document.

Comment: Yes, only one workbook in my case !! So does that mean if we delay the execution of code in Add-in using `Application.Wait` , it will refer to the real active document ?

Comment: I am afraid not. Try declaring two variables `Dim wb As Workbook, wbAct as Workbook` then `For each wb in Workbooks` If wb.name <> thisworkbook.name Then Set wbAct = wb` `Next`.   Then use `wbAct` instead of `ActiveDocument`.

Comment: Can you post it in comment so i can mark it as solution @FaneDuru ?

Comment: Ups... I commented here by mistake. No need to post an answer. There were only some pieces of advice. If I would post something, it should be a little different. I was driving and changed some message to another user after I posted a complex answer. Your comment came exactly after I asked if the solution works. Being to a trafic light, I wrote the above comment. I will delete it...